# Inversion for adverbial prepositional phrases

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I do not fully understand how to use inversion for prepositional phrases. If I am not wrong, not all the sentence with prepositional phrases can be inverted; it depends on the verb. Thus, I'd like to know more verbs that can be inverted. I just know a few, for example, lie and be.
Example: 
- under the tree lies a tall dog.
- at the corner of street is my sister.

I've seen people inverted the verb 'cover'. As in, Inside the room was covered by mondern paintings. Is it correct?

Comment: This might help you greatly. http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html

Comment: 'The room was-covered-by/in modern paintings.' This is a verb in the passive voice.  ="Modern paintings covered the room."   Here **inside** is an adverb meaning 'on the other side of the door.'; if you use it as a preposition (=inside-the-room), you leave the sentence without a subject. The adverb coming first has created a **local** **syntactic** **ambiguity**.

Comment: I see. Anyway, what if I insert a subject? Can I say, inside the room was walls covered by mondern paintings? Or can I use, the inside of the room was cover by mondern paintings?

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer. The verb in your example is "was" and "covered" is a past participle. Your sentence should read, "Inside the room, modern paintings covered the walls" if you want to use cover correctly.

Your construction "was covered" is passive voice, and most grammar books suggest that you avoid it.

Comment: Most grammar books don't suggest this. Only bad style guides do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a difficult question to answer but I guess, if to search in details, a lot of such words can be found. for instance,

**My elder brother rushed in.**- ***In rushed my elder brother***

Comment: If I was an expert I would remove my Icon. If **you** want to remove it, simply edit the page yourself. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

[1] **Inside : the room : was covered : by modern paintings**
...adverb..........SS...............VV...................adverbial phrase[Ph].

Your sentence is very, very close to showing inversion after a prepositional phrase.
But here are the five things you need to make it so.

1  There must be a prepositional phrase **of place**. (of course)
2  The verb must be a **linking** verb, not an action verb.
3  The **revelation** must be more important than the 'place'.  And of course
4   You must identify the subject.
5  And you must be able to work the inverted/uninverted switch.

The **local ambiguity** will make an *adverbial phrase of place*. "glowed" can be the linking verb.  Subject  'modern pictures.

> [2] (Inverted) Inside the room [Ph] glowed [V] modern pictures[SS].
>   [3] (uninverted) Modern pictures [SS] glowed [V] inside the room[Ph(place)].

Simplify the verb(glowed->is) and decorate the modern pictures with an adjectival phrase and we have almost the same words as your original sentenc **with a completely different syntax.**

> [4] Inside the room [Ph(place)] were[V]  fabulous modern pictures[SS]
>   covering the walls[Ph(Adj)]
>   [5] =(no inversion)Modern pictures were covering the walls inside the room.
>    OR [6]= There were modern pictures covering the walls inside the
>   room.

"fabulous" is only there to build the 'revelation.'
Now for your second question.

Linking words that work are is/was, appeared, seemed.

is/was can be replaced by stood, lay, remained, (static verbs)
appeared can be replaced by glowed, twinkled, glowered.
This list is not exhaustive.

Comment: Would you mind explaining me some key terms, revelation (point number 3) and local ambiguity? Thx

Comment: **revelation**  inversion is often used in outside television reports: " In the doorway behind me stands the (richest man in the world, or whatever)" And the figure works well if there is a bit of drama. For everyday events use SubjectVerbPhrase. A man stands in the doorway.

Comment: **Local** **Ambiguity** makes the reader stumble and start again. Here's a site for that   http://www.fun-with-words.com/ambiguous_garden_path.html .Your sentence began with ' Inside the room' which looks like a prepositional phrase. But then "...was covered by modern paintings," doesn't make any sense. So you have to start again.

Comment: Not sure about your linking verb stipulation: "Into the valley of death rode the 500", "Here comes Bob" etc.

Comment: @Araucaria Touché.  í must back track and find my source for that. And Turkan's post too disproves it.